Spawn Gazebo entity with odom_frame not at the map origin
I am simulating a robot inside a Gazebo world for SLAM with slam_toolbox.
I spawn the robot via spawn_entity, and it has a planar_move plugin so it can be controlled via teleop_twist_keyboard and publishes the odometry topic and the odom_frame -> base_link tf.
The problem is, the odom_frame always starts at the (0,0,0) of the gazebo world, and if I spawn the robot at (8,9,0) for instance, the odom_frame -> base_link reflects this correctly. But I would like for the odom_frame to start at any random pose so the odom_frame -> base_link transform starts as the identity.
I need this because I am testing some algorithms to re-use maps with robots that start at random positions inside of the map.
